# 'error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1' while installing python-fcl

Tags: python

I wanted to `pip3 install` [python-fcl](https://github.com/BerkeleyAutomation/python-fcl) after installing all the prerequisites.

But I get the following error message every time:

```
Installing collected packages: python-fcl
Running setup.py install for python-fcl ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-install-ztdk03wt/python-fcl_898f6f205407433c8edb2de3ddd6c8cd/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-install-ztdk03wt/python-fcl_898f6f205407433c8edb2de3ddd6c8cd/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-record-az5xic3w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/python-fcl
     cwd: /private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-install-ztdk03wt/python-fcl_898f6f205407433c8edb2de3ddd6c8cd/
Complete output (27 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fcl
copying fcl/collision_data.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fcl
copying fcl/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fcl
copying fcl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fcl
running build_ext
cythoning fcl/fcl.pyx to fcl/fcl.cpp
building 'fcl.fcl' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fcl
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c fcl/fcl.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fcl/fcl.o -std=c++11
In file included from fcl/fcl.cpp:631:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1944:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
fcl/fcl.cpp:656:10: fatal error: 'fcl/data_types.h' file not found
#include "fcl/data_types.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-install-ztdk03wt/python-fcl_898f6f205407433c8edb2de3ddd6c8cd/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-install-ztdk03wt/python-fcl_898f6f205407433c8edb2de3ddd6c8cd/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/n4/tf_wp68d6lv0xf_4js8_5_kc0000gn/T/pip-record-az5xic3w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/python-fcl Check the logs for full command output.
```

Since other people seem to get the error `command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` in other cases unrelated to python-fcl too, I am guessing, that it's something I have set up wrong with my python installation. But I can't figure out what would fix it.

Comment: Please provide a link for exactly what package you are using. I see a lot of things named `python-fcl` when I try to search.

Comment: my bad, I edited the question

Comment: The Github project you link to is a couple years old, it seems to rely on interfaces in https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl which are now in `.deprecated`. Maybe start over and try installing an older version of that? Maybe see also https://github.com/BerkeleyAutomation/python-fcl/issues/19

Comment: I understand that it's wonky either way. But could deprecated interfaces really cause the error I'm getting?

Comment: If code A was written against version B1 and version B2 now no longer exposes the interface which was current when B1 was the current version, this is exactly what you should expect. Either update A to target B2 instead, if you can figure out how, or roll back to B1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an older version of FCL - in my case, `0.5` instead of `0.7`.

The credit for the answer should really go to [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) for the link he posted in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Your install is failing because you don't have the python development headers installed.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: That is very often the problem, but this is not one of those cases. (If this was one of those questions, you should nominate it as a duplicate of an existing question, rather than post a new answer, anyway.)